# Strange Posture of NAO Robot

Tags: nao-robot

[image]

The Aldebaran NAO robot suddenly stop moving. It boots properly, and can be accessed webpage and Choregraphe.
However, it shows the strange posture as attached photo, and never moves it's motors.

Tried hard reset, and re-install naoqi, but no luck yet.
Any recommendation for resolving this strange issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your robot is decalibrated.
You will need to [contact to the support](https://www.softbankrobotics.com/emea/en/support/nao-6/contact).

Comment: Dear @Victor Thanks so much. Is there any way to check the low level log whether all parts works well? Also, i’ve been inherited the NAO. So if the arm or hand is replaced, (with the same part of another NAO) does the new part cannot recognized?

Comment: If you can move the joints with Choregraphe, it certainly works.

Comment: It doesn’t work. the joint doesn’t reflect the movement in Choregraphe. I am suspect any ‘matching’ between board ids or the software level issue since I checked all lines.

Comment: Is there any way to get the low-level HW log using qicli?

Comment: Please write a separate question for that.

Comment: I written a question below. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67763570/nao-robot-low-level-logs-of-each-board)