# Nao robot low level logs of each board

Tags: nao-robot

Is it possible to see the low level log of each boards control each joint?
(i.e. whether the board in right arm is connected and detected?)

My Nao’s right hand stopped moving. So, I replaced it with the parts from broken one.
Electrically, everything seems Ok(I tested the connectivity with tester), but the hand is still not working.

Does the part S/N matters even the replaced part is exactly same part id?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no access to the logs from the other boards of NAO.
However, there is a reasonable amount of low-level data that is [accessible with Monitor](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao6/naoqi-developer-guide/choregraphe-suite/monitor). There is a "Memory Viewer", and a [list of memory keys available](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao6/nao-documentation/nao-developer-guide/actuator-sensor-list#actuator-sensor-list-naov6).